# yupError.inner is undefined while integrating schema with Formik

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I tried integrating the Yup's Schema validation with formik. But receiving error as **yupError.inner is undefined**
Here's a link to [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/input-form-ng8s3)!

I have'nt tried much. But found this bug report. which was later realized to be resolved. But still i'm recieving the same. Link to issue [#1486](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/1486)!.

```
// VALIDATION SCHEMA
const formSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    emailId: Yup.string("Enter a valid string")
      .email("Please enter a valid Email ID")
      .required("Need your Email ID, we won't spam you!"),
    confirmMail: Yup.string("Enter a valid string")
      .matches(Yup.ref("emailId"), "Email ID's are not matching")
      .required("Please enter a valid mailid"),
    mobileNo: Yup.number("Please enter number")
      .max(10, "You've entered more than 10 numbers")
      .min(10, "You've entered less than 10 numbers")
      .required("Password is required"),
    password: Yup.string("Enter a valid password").required(
      "Password field is required"
    ),
    confirmPassword: Yup.string("Enter a valid password").required(
      "Password fields are not matching"
    )
  });
```

```
          //Integration of Validation
          <Formik
            validate
            initialValues={this.initialValues}
            validationSchema={this.formSchema}
            onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
          >
            {props => this.renderForm(props)}
          </Formik>
```

Recieving the error *yupError.inner is undefined*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bumpup yup to [latest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup) and use `mixed().test()` instead of `string().test()`

example :

```
passwordConfirm: Yup.mixed().test('is-same', 'Passwords not match.', value => value === values.newPassword)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the custom validation for matching the e-mail fields.  I made a fork [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/input-form-xxtmu) which I fixed using the method from [this Github issue](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/90) to add a custom validation method to Yup for comparing equality of fields, a feature which is apparently not well-supported.